# Prove that the solution of an ODE can be prolonged to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need an help understanding some general techniques in ordinary differential equations. I've never attended a course on ODE, so I'm quite confused on the argument, but I'm trying to improve my knowledgle.

We have the following Cauchy problem: $$\begin{cases}\frac{dv}{dt}=b(v(t)+f(t))\\
v(s)=0\end{cases}$$ 
where

- $b\in C^1(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n)$ and it is monotone, i.e. $\left<b(x)-b(y),x-y\right>\leq k(1+|x-y|^2)\quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb R^n.$
- $f:[s,+\infty]\to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous.

We know that a  unique solution $v$ exists defined on the interval $[s,T)$ (since $F(t,x):=b(x+f(t))$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $x$).
We want to prove that we can prolong the solution to $+\infty$, i.e. there exists a unique solution defined on $[s,+\infty).$

Now:

1. Using monotonicity assumption on $b$ we have that $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}|v(t)|^2=\left< \frac{d}{dt}v(t),v(t)\right> \leq C(1+|v(t)|^2);$$
2. Integrating the above expression on the interval $[s,t]$ and using Gronwall's Lemma we have $$|v(t)|^2\leq 2C(T-s)e^{2C(T-s)}, \quad \forall t\in[s,T).$$

I've written on my notes that from 1. and 2. follows $$\sup_{t\in[s,T)} \left|\frac{dv}{dt}\right|=R_T<\infty,\tag{$*$}$$ and so we can prolong the solution to $\infty$. Now, I agree with the fact that if the solution does not explode we can prolong it, but I don't get why from 1. and 2. follows $(*).$

Can someone help me? Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property $2$ shows that $v$ is bounded on $[s,T)$. Since $b$ is continuous, the right hand side of 
$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=b(v(t)+f(t))
$$
is bounded on $[s,T)$. This gives $(*)$.